# Wordpress: automatically convert custom field to custom taxonomy?

Tags: wordpress, custom-fields, custom-taxonomy

I have this custom post type called "listing". People can use a front-end form to create a new listing. This front-end form has a custom field called "app_city". Now when someone submits the form, I would like this custom field value to be converted automatically to a term in the custom taxonomy "Cities" (under my cystom post type "listing").

Is such a thing possible to accomplish?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes it is possible through [wp_insert_term()](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_insert_term). But you have to digg your front-end form that handle the `app_city` custom field data. Just Use the `wp_insert_term()` after everything verified from the form.

Comment: Thank you, see my comment below.

Comment: @RobbertT You should update/edit your answer, instead of creating new one every time.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so this worked for me.
Thanks!

```
    $parent_term = term_exists( 'Cities' ); // array is returned if taxonomy is given
    $parent_term_id = $parent_term['term_id']; // get numeric term id
$city = $_POST['app_plaatsnaam'];    
wp_insert_term(
    $_POST['app_city'], // the term 
      'Cities', // the taxonomy
      array(
        'parent'=> $parent_term_id
      )
    );

wp_set_object_terms( $listing_id, $city, 'Cities', false);
```